# Javascript Ajax call using password with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, passwords

I have a JavaScript page that makes an Ajax call like the code below. The PHP page is inside a corporate intranet and requires authentication in the domain (basic auth is disallowed). I collect the username (u) and password (p) from input fields using jQuery.

```
var u = $('#user').val();
var p = $('#pass').val();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain/mypage.php",
    username: u,
    password: p,
    error: function () {
    }
}).done(function(html) {
        //Do Stuff
});
```

The solution works very well...except when the user has a special character in their password. So far, it seems we're affected by: @ $ +.

It seems to me there is some conflict collecting passwords with symbols that also act as syntax operators in JavaScript...but how do you properly escape them to be submitted as a password?

Thanks!

Comment: I am quite sure that they are submitted properly. Have a look at the sent HTTP headers. Does your server expect that format?

Comment: You are sending username and password as a get request over http? Yikes, security nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd normally never do that, but in this case the data path is secured by another method so I'm not worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to URL encode the parameter. For JavaScript, take a look at [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Backend framework will understand it, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Really? I had expected jQuery to take care of that if it was needed

Comment: One would expect that, but in my experience, no.

Comment: @Bergi Maybe it only does that for the `data` param, not `username`/`password`. Never had to use them, interesting though

Comment: I just heard back from a user: this seems to have worked, at least for Amp and At..  Thanks! :)